# Django app - heroku[router] status=500

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku

Django 1.7 project
After deploying the project everything was fine.

But I had a problem with static files, as django itself doesn't serves them.

So , I've installed whitenoise and configured it.

After that I get status=500

**Heroku logs**

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=triiipjournal.herokuapp.com request_id=c658a601-dbb9-445f-8f43-8032ff4409dd fwd="178.212.111.37" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=129ms status=500 bytes=244
```

Comment: can you run collectstatic and check ?

Comment: Yea, it collects all static files